# Can't merge video and audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

The movie received when merging the files is not played. Here is information about the files:

> $ ffmpeg -hide_banner -i audio.m4a

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'audio.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 03:43:35.45, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 108 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 107 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

> $ ffmpeg -hide_banner -i video.mp4

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 03:43:35.90, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1737 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x406 [SAR 1:1 DAR 360:203], 1734 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

My playback device is Sony Bravia KDL-42W653A, separately the files are played. But if I merge them, then after playing about 20 minutes the file crash. To join, I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i 'video.mp4' -i 'audio.m4a' -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c copy movie.mp4
ffmpeg -i 'video.mp4' -i 'audio.m4a' -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 112k -async 1 movie.mp4
ffmpeg -i 'video.mp4' -i 'audio.m4a' -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 128k -af aresample=async=1:ocl='stereo':osr=48000 movie.mp4
```

I note, if I use ac3 codec, then the video is played. What's the problem here?

Comment: ffmpeg crashes?  I assume you're trying to "merge" them not concatenate?

Comment: @rogerdpack, The join is successful, but the file is not played by the device